# Can the traditional space of Euclidean vectors (with dot and cross products) be extended to be algebra over reals and what properties would it have?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, hypercomplex-numbers

There is traditional vector calculus of 3D vectors:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Basic_properties
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities

In this calculus we usually operate with 3-dimensional vectors and scalars.

But can we consider a sum of a vector and a scalar and define operations on them in such a way so that the vector calculus identities were generalized?

In other words, an algebra of elements of the form

$\mathbf{V}=a_0+a_1\mathbf{i}+a_2\mathbf{j}+a_3\mathbf{k}=a_0+\mathbf{v}$

There still would be dot and cross products (dot product still always scalar):

$\mathbf{V_1}\cdot \mathbf{V_2}=(a_0+\mathbf{v_1})\cdot(b_0+\mathbf{v_2})=a_0 b_0+\mathbf{v_1}\cdot\mathbf{v_2}$

$\mathbf{V_1}\times \mathbf{V_2}=(a_0+\mathbf{v_1})\times(b_0+\mathbf{v_2})=a_0 \mathbf{v_2}+b_0\mathbf{v_1}+\mathbf{v_1}\times\mathbf{v_2}$

Norm:
$||\mathbf{V}||=\sqrt{a_0^2+||\mathbf{v}||^2}=\sqrt{\mathbf{V}\cdot\mathbf{V}}$

And so on.

I wonder, what properties such algebra would have, can we define elementary functions in this space, particularly, logarithms, and how will it compare with hypercomplex numbers.

Comment: You might be interested in either [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_physical_space) or [the quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)!

Comment: If you modify your cross product slightly, by adding the product $\ a_0b_0\ $ to it and subtracting the dot product $\ \mathbf{v}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}_2\ $ from it:
$$
\mathbf{V}_1\times\mathbf{V}_2=a_0b_0-\mathbf{v}_1\cdot\mathbf{v}_2+a_0\mathbf{v}_2+b_0\mathbf{v}_1+\mathbf{v}_1\times\mathbf{v}_2
$$
you get the [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion).

Comment: @lonzaleggiera thanks! This is interesting! But my idea was to generalize the usual vector algebra.